# Determine orbit type from TLE

Tags: orbit, low-earth-orbit, geostationary, orbital-elements, two-line-elements

I was wondering if, and how, one can tell from the values in a TLE whether an orbit is LEO, MEO, HEO, or GEO. I'd like to do this in code eventually, so any formulas or threshold values would be much appreciated.

Comment: @diamond answer is missing definition of `u`. Here is the answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18291/51924.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set#Format), field 8 of TLE line 2 is the "mean motion in revolutions per day"; you can determine the orbital period from this.

For geosynchronous orbit, you should expect 1.0 revolutions per day (in fact, due to [complexity in the definition of "day"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_period#Earth), they're very close to [1.0027](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/geo.txt) as a rule).

[LEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) defined as < 2000 km altitude should get periods between 84 and 127 minutes (i.e. ~11 to ~17 revolutions per day).

[MEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Earth_orbit) defined as 2000 km to geostationary would then be 1-11 revs a day.

[HEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Earth_orbit) defined as higher than geostationary would be less than 1 rev per day.

Highly elliptical orbits complicate this, obviously; it's up to you how you want to classify a satellite with perigee in LEO and apogee in MEO. You can [derive the SMA from the period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period#Small_body_orbiting_a_central_body), and the [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) is in line 2 field 5, if you want the actual perigee and apogee.

Comment: Very nice.  Had never seen the fields broken down.

Comment: At least in the fields I have experience in, HEO refers to Highly Eccentric Orbit or High Eccentricity Orbit.  I don't think I've ever seen it used to refer to High Earth Orbit.  Those are rare - as a collective term, I think we usually refer to them as super-sync.

Answer (score 4):

The TLE gives mean motion ($n$) in $\frac{rev}{day}$. This needs to be converted to $\frac{rad}{s}$ which can be accomplished by multiplying the $n$ TLE value by $\frac{2\pi}{86400}$.

Therefore, to go directly from $n$ in TLE to the semi-major axis $a$. We can use the following formula: $a=\frac{u^{1/3}}{\frac{2n\pi}{86400}^{2/3}}$.

From here, orbital regimes can be determined ($100km<a\leq2000km$ means LEO, $2000km<a<35786km$ is MEO and GEO is ~$35,786km$).

There are other complexities around eccentricity, and for GEO you'll want to include bounds on inclination.

Comment: For GEO it might be more intuitive and accurate to select directly on mean motion directly (e.g. ~1.0027 rev/day for synchrony to a sidereal day) rather than to derive the Eulerian (and therefore approximate) value for $a$. Even out there J2 has a 100 ppm effect on the period (you can't just use $\mu$). [Equation for orbital period around oblate bodies, based on J2?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25868/12102)

Comment: Also your $a$ is the semi-major axis, but then you re-use $a$ for altitude in your inequalities, don't forget the [6378 km!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23847/12102), and don't forget inclination! Geosynchronous is not necessarily geostationary.

Comment: I would disagree about being more selective for GEO - there are lots of GEO objects which are oscillating about the GEO orbit (old satellites, debris) and these to me also count as GEO. D'oh on the altitude - definitely don't forget the 6378!

Comment: If it were me I would give the best possible information first, then offer the various options for simplifying. It's just a thought. Now it's at least here in comments anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can download TLE data for each of these orbit regimes separately with the click of a link at https://www.space-track.org/#recent *after registering and agreeing to the terms of the site*.  The definitions used there are:

- HEO: Eccentricity > 0.25
- GEO: 0.99 <= Mean Motion <= 1.01 and Eccentricity < 0.01
- MEO: 600 minutes <= Period <= 800 minutes and Eccentricity < 0.25
- LEO: Mean Motion > 11.25 and Eccentricity < 0.25

In this usage, HEO definitely means Highly Elliptical Orbit, not "High Earth".  Note also the fairly restrictive definition of "Medium", for mean motion between 1.8 and 2.4 , such that there are portions of the parameter space that don't fit any of these names.  This is not really a problem in practice, as there are very few actual objects having orbit elements falling into one of the unnamed regions.