# Major axis larger than total of apogee and perigee?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

I am trying to calculate the apogee and perigee using the orbital elements. I am checking my results against CALSPHERE 1 (https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=900).

I am getting 7363599.5m as the semi major axis (a), but for the apogee and perigee, I am getting 7382482.0m and 7344717.0m respectively. I am using e as
I am using the formulas:
perigee = (1 - e)a
apogee = (1 + e)a

I am totally confused how the major axis (semi major axis * 2.0) can be larger than the total of minimum distance and max distance from the earth? Am I crucially misunderstanding this?

Comment: On the linked page, the apogee and perigee numbers don't include the radius of the Earth (they are measured from some theoretical Earth surface).  They are *altitudes*. The semi-major axis *does* include the radius of the Earth. Therefore, on that page, the semi-major axis is also larger than the sum of the two altitudes.  Perhaps your numbers follow the same logic.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're confused by, except that you've misstated that the major axis is the semi-major axis * 0.5.  It's the other way around; the major axis is 2*a.  Your perigee, apogee, and semi-major axis all seem to check out.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you that's exactly it. I didn't realise they see it as from the surface.

Comment: @ErinAnne Oops, I did write that, got muddled! The question was answered by Organic, the linked page seems subtract radius of earth

Comment: Cool.  Welcome to Space SE!

Comment: You may find these helpful as well: [Failing at getting apogee and perigee from TLE](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57276/12102) and [How is the altitude of a satellite defined, given that the Earth is not spherical?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23842/12102) and [How big is an orbit of "X by Y miles"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49625/12102)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the linked page, the apogee and perigee numbers don't include the radius of the Earth (they are measured from some theoretical Earth surface). They are *altitudes*. The semi-major axis *does* include the radius of the Earth.

This is the reason for the apparent discrepancy.